# Login Loop from hell!: chown'd .Xauthority in 'username:username' and tried update and upgrade

Tags: login, 19.04, 19.10

While on Ubuntu 19.04 I updated && upgrade && reboot to land on a login screen which never ends.... I've chown'd .Xauthority for the username from root user and updated from 19.04 to 19.10. Sill having issues. Hoping this isn't too vague and also this is my first post so please forgive my ignorance of any customs that I'm not following with this post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you end up here after running `sudo startx`? Nevertheless:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell.

Now run `ls -lA`. If you see the line

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try logging in (you may also need to do the same for `.ICEauthority)`.

Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
2. or uninstall, reinstall it.

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> until you reach the login screen again, and restart.